# HTML Twitter Bootstrap tooltip reinitialization (dynamic tooltip title)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm new with the Bootstrap and jquery and I have a big problem with it and didn't find answer for it.

The case:
I have a text, which has tooltip and popover also. With the popover I show an input field and a button. After the button pressed, the "tooltip-title" changes to the input value. This works. But... I can't destroy, and reinitialize the tooltip, so it doesn't show the new title.

The code:

```
$('.note').each(
  function() {
    $(this).popover({
      placement: 'auto',
      html: true,
      content: returnNoteInput($(this), $(this).attr("tooltip-title"), $(this).attr("input")),
      title: "Jegyzet módosítása"
    })
    $(this).tooltip({
      placement: 'bottom',
      title: $(this).attr("tooltip-title")
    })
  });

function returnNoteInput(inputValue, inputTarget) {
  eredmeny = "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" + inputValue + "\"></input>";
  eredmeny += "<button onclick=\"setValue(this, '" + inputTarget + "')\")>módosítás</button>"
  return eredmeny;
}

function setValue(ele, targetId) {
  document.getElementById(targetId).value = ele.previousElementSibling.value;
  noteElement = document.getElementById(targetId).nextElementSibling;

  noteElement.setAttribute("tooltip-title", ele.previousElementSibling.value);
}
```

So everything is working (I can see the tooltip-title changing) except I can't reinitialize the tooltip (I didn't copied my tries, because it didn't succeed).

Edit:Note: I have an other input field, just to see if it's working or not.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function setValue(ele, targetId){
    document.getElementById(targetId).value=ele.previousElementSibling.value;
    noteElement= $('#'+targetId).next();
    noteElement.attr("tooltip-title",ele.previousElementSibling.value);
    noteElement.tooltip("destroy");
    noteElement.popover("destroy");

    setTimeout(function() {
        noteElement.tooltip({placement : 'bottom',title : noteElement.attr("tooltip-title")})
        noteElement.popover({placement : 'auto',html:true,content: returnNoteInput(noteElement.attr("tooltip-title"),noteElement.attr("input")), title :"Jegyzet módosítása"})
        }
            ,1000)
    }
```